# How can you retrieve a signature of function usable in Excel in VBA or a DLL?

Tags: excel, vba, xll

When you type a function and press CTRL + SHIFT + A, you get a completion in Excel for the rest of the arguments.

For example, try to type, =SUM(, then press CTRL + SHIFT + A, and you will get the following:

```
=sum(number1,number2,...)
```

My question is: how do you retrieve this signature from either VBA or a XLL, such as you can implement either your own function wizard or a macro to help input the data faster.

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare your variables as variants, then the intellisense should kick in. i.e., instead of:
`Dim X as object`
Try
`Dim X as excel.application`
Then all the needed variables for that function will be shown to you in a yellow overlay.

It doesn't output the 'signature' to editable text like ctrl-shift-A does, but it serves the same purpose.

Comment: I was more wondering about how to get them programatically not within the editor.

Comment: Hmm, can't help you then. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://nxll.codeplex.com. Every add-in function is a first class object that you can query for this information.